# Jquery slider (php values in query)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

need your help with Jquery slider.

my jquery code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#price_filter').val(<?php echo $min; ?>-<?php echo $max; ?>);
      $("#price_slider").slider({
        min: <?php echo $min; ?>,
        max: <?php echo $max; ?>,
        values:[<?php echo $min; ?>, <?php echo $max; ?>],
        step: 100,
        range:true,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#price_range_label").html('$' + ui.values[ 0 ] + ' - ' + ui.values[ 1 ] + '$' );
          $('#price_filter').val(ui.values[0] + ' -' + ui.values[1]).trigger('change');
        }
      });

      $('#status :checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#all_status').on('click', function(){
        $('#status :checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
      });

      FilterJS(services, "#service_list", {
        template: '#template',
        criterias:[
          {field: 'amount', ele: '#price_filter', type: 'range'},
          {field: 'status', ele: '#status :checkbox'}

        ],

      });
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<center><span id="price_range_label" style="margin:10px;">
<?=$min; ?>-<?=$max; ?> USD.</i></span></center>
<br/>
<div id="price_slider"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="price_filter" value='<?php echo $min; ?>-<?php echo $max; ?>'/>
```

The problem is when i select max range and slide it to min all items somewhere has gone. this slider works correctly only if I slide from min to max.

Also i have a huge values (for example min 500 max 10000000)

What i'm doing wrong? can anyone help me to solve it? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PHP code in jQuery. You can put values to jQuery like `$(element).attr('attribute');` or `$(element).val();`

You just write into HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="min" value="<?p=$min;?>">
<input type="hidden" id="max" value="<?p=$max;?>">
```

And in jQuery:

```
min: $('#min').val(),
max: $('#max').val(),
values:[$('#min').val(), $('#max').val()],
```

Comment: Thank you! But Jquery didn't recognize values. in the source code in browser there are no values for min and max. [code] jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        
          $("#price_slider").slider({
            min: $('#min').val(),
            max: $('#max').val(),
            values:[$('#min').val(), $('#max').val()],  
            step: 100,
            range: true, [/code]

Comment: jQuery is client side progress. You cannot see in source code. If you want to know, what values is in jQuery, you must add `console.log("MIN:" + min +  "MAX" + max);` into jQuery.

Like:
 `slide: function(event, ui) {
         console.log("MIN:" + min +  "MAX" + max);`

And look at console in browser - CTRL + SHIFT + J or F12

Comment: Yes, I know, and unfortunately with your example slider doesn't work, cause min and max values didn't recognize. :(

Comment: Because you haven't values in PHP code.

<input type="hidden" id="min" value="VALUE FROM PHP">
<input type="hidden" id="max" value="VALUE FROM PHP">

Comment: input fileds have getting values from PHP. Min - 660; Max - 12300

Comment: in console there no values. :( but will try again now

Comment: Sorry, my bad:

`console.log("MIN:" + $('#min').val() + "MAX: " + $('#max').val());`

But it shows you only 660 and 12300 values. If you want to look at values from slider:

`console.log("MIN:" + ui.values[ 0 ] + "MAX: " + ui.values[ 1 ] );`

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative to using jQuery plugins for slider functionality is to use native support for range input. It is supported in **[(FF23+, Chrome 4+, Safari 3.1+, Opera 10+, Android 2.1 and IE10+)](http://caniuse.com/#search=range)**.

You can style it and use jQuery for event listening.

Here is an example:

```js
$('.slider').on('change input', function() {
  $('.text').text($(this).val());
});
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -3.6px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ac51b5;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='slider' type="range" min="50" max="500000" value="100" />
<div class='text'>
50
</div>
```

and here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nu2m0cm9/